# PHPExcel - locking the file being viewed

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have an excel report which need to be locked from viewing without password authentication. I have tried with following snippets but it's only making it write protect. following is the code snippets I used.

```
$phpExcelObject->getSecurity()->setLockWindows(true);
$phpExcelObject->getSecurity()->setLockStructure(true);
$phpExcelObject->getSecurity()->setWorkbookPassword("password");
```

I am using PHPExcel version 1.8.

Seems like this is a know issue with PHPExcel

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/442

Is there any alternative library for this which I can use to make my report password protected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an option that PHPExcel supports. If you want to lock a file for reading, then you're very limited in your alternatives. The only libraries  that I'm aware of capable of preventing read access to a file without a password are PHP's [COM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php), which requires a COM enabled spreadsheet program such as MS Excel or OpenOffice Calc running on the server; the Open Office alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)), which requires Open Office installed on the server with Java support enabled; and [Ilia Alshanetsky's Excel extension](https://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) from [github](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel), that requires the commercial [libXL component](http://www.libxl.com/) installed on your server.